# How To Write Correct Path Of These Files?

Tags: php

I have an PHP file located here :

```
/public_html/folder1/folder2/index.php
```

and this file requires CSS file located here :

```
/public_html/folderX/folderY/css1.css
```

what is the correct path to access that CSS file should I put in the index.php? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `public_html` is your root:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/folderX/folderY/css1.css" />
```

My personal advice is not to meddle with relative paths; they will only get you into trouble when you start moving your PHP scripts around; or worse, when your code gets included as part of another script and you have no way of knowing where that is.

The same thing could be said for references inside your CSS (images); it's not always immediately obvious that relative paths inside CSS files are taken from the location of that file as opposed to inline CSS, which uses the location of the page.

Answer (score 4):

You can either add it relatively to the document:

`../../folderX/folderY/css1.css`

Or relatively to the document root:

`/folderX/folderY/css1.css`