# how to write path for files in sibling folders?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Folder1 and folder 2 are within a folder. Folder 1 has sub folder and a file within a sub folder. I want to access xyz file on to abc file. This is what I tried and it is not working - `'../folder1/somefolder/xyz.css`

```
folder1
 | |
 | |_ somefolder
 |      |
 |      |_ xyz.css
 |
folder2
 | |
 | |_ abc.html
 |
```

Comment: Where did you try this? Please show us your code and tell us what it is you are trying to accomplish by accessing the css file. I assume you're trying to use the CSS file, do you have a <link> tag?

Comment: Yes. Apparently it was just `/somefolder/xyz.css`. This is the answer to my own question.

Comment: @AnnGilardo If you have an answer, feel free to write and accept an answer to your own question. If, on the other hand, you consider this question has no value for the larger community, you might consider another course of action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was just /somefolder/xyz.css. This is the answer to my own question.

Comment: If anyone is interested this is another question that I found useful and will help beginners in understanding the file path . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043141/how-to-write-correct-path-of-these-files